# What does "even had the Archaic Greeks thought in such terms" means?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, as

my friends,

I have a question from a book. Here is the quote:

> The appeal to massive supernatural forces in order to account for
> large-scale physical events is explanation of a sort: but it appears
> piecemeal and ad hoc, and does not lend itself to general formulation
> in the form of useful physical laws, **even had the Archaic Greeks
> thought in such terms,as they did not.**

The tricky part for me is the part that starts with "even had", the bold part. I am not sure whether "had" in this sentence is a conditional that means "if" or not. Furthermore, I did not understand "as they did not" part as well. To whom "they" refer? Does "as" in the sentence indicate time or cause? Please help me with that.

The book is "Cause and explanation" by R. J. Hankinson. Here is the full paragraph for those who are interested:

> It has sometimes been suggested that the divine mechanism of the
> Homeric poems is simply intended as metaphorical ornamentation,and as
> such should not be taken seriously; but there is little reason to
> believe this.4 Earthquakes are caused because Poseidon, ‘the
> earth-shaker’,is displeased with some segment of humanity. Lightning
> and thunder are the arms of Zeus. The appeal to massive supernatural
> forces in order to account for large-scale physical events is
> explanation of a sort: but it appears piecemeal and ad hoc, and does
> not lend itself to general formulation in the form of useful physical
> laws,5 even had the Archaic Greeks thought in such terms,as they did
> not. Equally,the cosmogonies and the structural accounts cannot be
> subjected to empirical test,and no evidence is adduced in favour of
> them.

Comment: Even [if] the Archaic Greeks had thought in such terms and they did not. It is just the be verb inversion and he left out the if, which is allowed.

Comment: Thank you so much Lambie for your answer. Then I have one thing to ask. Why he put "as". He could say "Even [if] the Archaic Greeks had thought in such terms they did not." What is the function of "as" here? Thank you so much again :)

Comment: [correction: why did he put x :)] Personally, I think that is an editing error and it should read: and they did not.

Comment: I think it's slightly unusual, but makes sense: _as_  is almost a resumptive pronoun here, as in _...as he said_, or _...as I thought_. You can nearly replace it with _which_.

Comment: @ColinFine Call it what you like, it does not sound right. Which they did not is the same here as: and they did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is discussing the Greek (or Homeric) assertion that actions of the gods cause things like floods or earthquakes. He notes that as an explanation it's not very useful, because it is not a (modern) physical law that would see these causes in a general framework (formulation) - one that today would be tested by making predictions.

The sentence that puzzles you follows. It asserts that the Archaic Greeks could not have found such a framework even if they had looked for one. They did not even look.

Comment: Thank you so much Ethan Bolker. As far as I understand "as" in the sentence seems to function like "whereas" or "which in fact" in terms of meaning. Can I understand in this way: "Ancient mythical assertions do not provide flourishing explanations, even if the Archaic Greeks had thought within such assertions, in which in fact they had not thought"

Comment: @grammarian Yes, your paraphrase captures the meaning. I might change a few of your words. "useful" instead of "flourishing", "about such assertions in a systematic way" instead of "within such assertions".

Comment: Thank you so much again :)